# Format List<T> to concatenate fields

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I've looked at hundreds of similar questions on SO to the one asked, but haven't found my answer. If this has been asked before, please accept my apologies.

I have a SQL database with a column of cities and a column of their states respectively. I use the Entity Framework as my DAL and in my BLL have lots of LINQ to format, move stuff, etc. I have on my UI a drop-down which currently accepts a `ToList()` from a method in my BLL and all works well, but I need to alter this method to return city and state, separated by a comma.  I have this so-far (which doesn't work!):

```
public static List<char> GetCitiesInCountryWithState(string isoalpha2)
{
    const string delimiter = ",";
    using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
    {
        var query = from c in ctx.Cities
                    join ctry in ctx.Countries on c.CountryId equals ctry.CountryId
                    where ctry.IsoAlpha2 == isoalpha2
                    select new { c.CityName, c.State };
        var cities = query.Select(i => i.CityName).Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimiter + j);
        return cities.ToList();  
    }
}
```

I've tried numerous LINQ variations, but I'm obviously not getting this correct. Can anyone offer some help please? As always, it is appreciated :)

**EDIT 1**: I'd like the output of the method to be a list of concatenated City names and states separated by a comma and a space; for example:

```
Miami, Florida
Key West, Florida
New York, New York
Boston, Massachusetts
```

Input is simply the ISO-Alpha2 code for the country in question, in the case of my example: 'US'.  This could be 'GB' for Great Britain or 'FR' for France or 'DE' for Germany for instance.

Comment: It's really not clear exactly what you want the output to be - a `List<char>` seems unlikely. Sample input and output data would be useful.

Comment: Probably the return type should be `List<string>`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks for the comment, I have edited the question above with the information. Agreed, `List<char>` is rather misleading - it's simply what I had so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Removed anonymous type
**Edit:** Added space in delimiter declaration to be a bit different :-) ", "

Hopefully I am not misunderstanding your question but you can add do it as follows by adding the delimiter in the return value of the query :

```
public static List<string> GetCitiesInCountryWithState(string isoalpha2)    
{
    const string delimiter = ", ";        
    using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())        
    {
        var query = from c in ctx.Cities                        
                    join ctry in ctx.Countries on c.CountryId equals ctry.CountryId 
                    where ctry.IsoAlpha2 == isoalpha2                        
                    select c.CityName + delimiter + c.State ;            
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

This will create a list of type string

Comment: Use `String.Concat(string,string,string)`

Comment: He probably also wants a space between the comma after city and the state, Better to use string.Format("{0}, {1}",c.CityName, c.State)

Comment: @ryber Maybe, but he asked for "city and state, separated by a comma" and that's what I gave :-)

Comment: @ryber @TBohnen.jnr thanks both for your answers - I am indeed looking for a city and state separated by a comma AND a space. +1 to both for prompt comments and reading OP :)

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr, either way, your answer works perfectly. Thank you very much for speedy answer and detailed comments +1...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<string> GetCitiesInCountryWithState(string isoalpha2)
{
    using (var context= new atomicEntities())
    {
        return (from city in context.Cities
                join country in context.Countries on c.CountryId equals country.CountryId
                where country.IsoAlpha2 == isoalpha2
                select String.Concat(city.CityName, ", ", city.State)
                // select String.Format("{0}, {1}", city.CityName, city.State)
                ).ToList();             
    }
}
```

---

FYI

You can also use `String.Join(string, IEnumerable<String>)` to get a result like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetCitiesInCountryWithState(string)

IEnumerable<string> r = GetCitiesInCountryWithState("100");
// { { "Miami, Florida" }, { "Key West, Florida" } }

string s = String.Join("; ", r);
// "Miami, Florida; Key West, Florida"
```

Comment: Would String.Concat result in a performance increase or why would you rather use that?