# Returning Concatenated String with LINQ for Dropdown

Tags: c#, linq

This is follow on from this question: [Format List<T> to concatenate fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611353/format-listt-to-concatenate-fields).  The answer was correct, but post-answer I wanted to return the `List` from the method so it could be re-used. I got this far, but this is not correct (because I know `Iqueryable` is not correct, it simply prevents the `AnonymousType` error):

```
public static IQueryable GetCitiesInCountryWithState(string isoalpha2)
    {
        const string delimiter = ", ";
        using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
        {
            var query = (from c in ctx.Cities
                        join ctry in ctx.Countries on c.CountryId equals ctry.CountryId
                        where ctry.IsoAlpha2 == isoalpha2
                        select new
                                   {
                                       CityId = c.CountryId,
                                       CityName = c.CityName + delimiter + c.State
                                   });
            return query;
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to return a `List<string>` here (if possible) and then do something like this on the UI:

```
ddlCity.DataSource = GetCitiesInCountryWithState(Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString());
            ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
            ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
            ddlCity.DataBind();
```

I've tried all sorts, but without luck. I know I've been close - but help is needed! Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option that you might look into:

On your City entity, I'm assuming you have a portion of a partial class generated by the EDM tools, and you may have another portion of the partial class which contains code that is not from the EDM generation.

In the non-generated portion of the partial class, you can add a transient property that gives the CityName and State as a readonly string (see below).  Transient means that the property is not persisted to the database, and is usually generated from some existing fields.  This technique is used a lot in ViewModels to provide more UI-friendly properties to a view.

```
public partial class City
{
    public string CityNameAndState
    {
        get
        {
            return CityName + delimiter + State;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use this as the DataTextField for your City object in the binding.  If you go this route, I don't think you'll need an anonymous type in the query - you can just return the City object as is.  The benefit of doing it this way vs. returning a custom object from the query is that if the property is defined on the class, you'll always have it, and it will always work the same no matter what query you use to retrieve Cities.

Hope that makes sense...  I made some assumptions on how your project is setup.

Comment: This sounds...fantastic. I must start using this on some of my projects. I had no idea you could do this, but seeing the code it seems so obvious! :)

Comment: I with @Sergio on this. I had no idea you could do this either! I am indeed running on the EF4.0 and with the POCO templates; so this - although not what I was expecting, is the correct answer! +1

Comment: Thank you @Andy White, superb answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return an Anonymous Type, the compiler can not maintain type safety.

So if you define a class

```
class City {
  public int CityId {get; set;}
  public string CityName {get; set;}
}
```

Replace your select new {} with select new City{} and return a List<City> or IQueryable<City> you should be fine.

Comment: So you're saying you cannot set an anonymous type to a `.DataSource`?

Comment: You can probably set it to a DataSource because the DataSource will be reflected, si no type checking is needed. But you can not return an Anonymous type from a method as you can not have a return type of "var", the caller would not know what it is.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you're saying. +1

Answer (score 1):

To expand for you taking what Chris said.

```
class City
```

{

```
   public int CityId {get; set;}
   public string CityName {get; set;}
```

}

and then

```
public static List<City> GetCitiesInCountryWithState(string isoalpha2)
{
    const string delimiter = ", ";
    using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
    {
        var query = (from c in ctx.Cities
                    join ctry in ctx.Countries on c.CountryId equals ctry.CountryId
                    where ctry.IsoAlpha2 == isoalpha2
                    select new City
                               {
                                   CityId = c.CountryId,
                                   CityName = c.CityName + delimiter + c.State
                               }).ToList();
        return query;
    }
}


var cityList = GetCitiesInCountryWithState(Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString());
ddlCity.DataSource = cityList;
ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
ddlCity.DataBind();
```